# js function repeats for all forms

Tags: javascript

this code below ( example not working not included libraries ) calculate distance between two coordinate, but in my case this code perform only one form (firs), for example if on the page more than one form, this code will not calculate second form, how to push this code to calculate all form for example I have more than 100's this forms on a page.

Thanks you.

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
            
                const lat1 = document.querySelector('#lat1').value;
                const lon1 = document.querySelector('#lon1').value;
                const lat2 = document.querySelector('#lat2').value;
                const lon2 = document.querySelector('#lon2').value;
                const p1 = new LatLon(Dms.parseDMS(lat1), Dms.parseDMS(lon1));
                const p2 = new LatLon(Dms.parseDMS(lat2), Dms.parseDMS(lon2));
                const dist = parseFloat(p1.distanceTo(p2).toPrecision(4));
                document.querySelector('#result-distance').textContent = dist;
});
```

```html
 <form>
        Lat 1: <input type="hidden" name="lat1" id="lat1"  value="25.434345" >
        Lon 1: <input type="text" name="lon1" id="lon1" value="55.902223445" >
        Lat 2: <input type="text" name="lat2" id="lat2" value="25.8944324" >
        Lon 2: <input type="text" name="lon2" id="lon2" value="55.893445">
        
        <output id="result-distance"></output> metres
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting issue because if you add two `form` in your page with same element ids, it always refer to the last one , that is the issue.

solution is try to give id to form than than get child input element of that form and do perform calculation.

you can do like this

```
var children = el.getElementsByTagName('fromid');
  for(var i = 0; i< children.length;i++)
  {
    if (children[i].getAttribute('id') == 'child') 
    {
     // do what ever you want with the element..  
     // children[i] holds the element at the moment..
    }
  }
```

Comment: Pranay is right, however if you don't want to make those changes, you can change JavaScript function to read current form submitted and read first input, second input and so on,. However that means sequence of input and what they represent must be same in all forms. E.g. 1st input lat1, 2nd input log1, 3rd input lat2, 4th inputs log2 - then u can do it without giving unique id to all elements

Comment: @user769889 - as per my knowledge i dont see other way if there is only pure javascript , but there is better way in jquery ..

Comment: I'm sure you can get current form submitted without knowing form id.  Or move listener to button pressed and then work out parent form and it's child. Sorry my first reply was very short cos on phone app there is no next line

Comment: hello, sorry Im  a bit confuse,   do I need add unique id for form ?

Comment: @antonpavlov - yes you need to apply uniqid for forms, and than you have to loop through all forms and calculate value you want